# Logarithm Laws Wrong Answer

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-function

$2^{2x}-4(2^x)-5=0$

is the question, if I do quadratic substitution or divide by 4 first I get the right answer of 2.32, if I do it any other way using logs I get the wrong answer. No matter if I use Log2, Ln, split it different ways, divide different ways. Always either get the answer to be negative of what it actually is or 4.32 or sometimes 0.32.

Here is one way I tried...

$2^{2x}-4(2^x)-5=0$
$2^{2x}-4(2^x)=5$
$2^{2x}-2^{2+x}=5$
$log_2(2^{2x})-log_2(2^{2+x})=log_2(5)$
$2x-(2+x)=log_2(5)$
$x-2=log_2(5)$
$x=4.32$

Clearly every time I'm doing it I'm doing something wrong but I have spent a good few hours and now I just want to know what it is.

Thank you

Comment: You can't split a log over subtraction like that.

Comment: $\log (a-b) \ne \log a - \log b$

Comment: $(a+b=c )\ne (\log a + \log b = \log c)$ . It is actually $\log(a+b) = \log c$

Comment: Thanks all, so is it just a coincidence that it works with dividing by 4 and then logging every term. If terms are split with addition/subtraction can you not log every term?

Comment: For $\;a,b>0\;,\;\;\log a-\log b=\log\frac ab\;$ .

Comment: It is a simple quadratic in the first instance, is $y^2 -4y -5 = 0$.  Solve for this, and then you can find $y = 2^x$, ie $x = \ln y / ln 2$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, and after the mistake has been commented:

$$2^{2x}-4\cdot2^x-5=0\implies (2^x-5)(2^x+1)=0\stackrel{\text{since}\,2^x+1>1}\implies 2^x=5\implies x=\frac{\log5}{\log2}$$